# Como distribuir os inputs em listas aleatoriamente?

Tags: python

Como faço para colocar o input de `nome` + `numero` + `outro` em uma coisa só e depois coloca-los em uma dessas listas (A, B, C ,D) de forma aleatória na linguagem Python?

```
A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []

for k in range(12):
    nome = input('Digite seu nome: ')
    numero = int(input('Um numero: ')
    outro = int(input('Outro numero: ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `choice` do módulo `random` passando uma lista com todas as suas listas como argumento. O que essa função faz é retornar um elemento dessa lista aleatoriamente.

```
lista_de_nomes = ["João", "Maria", "Pedro", "Lucas", "Gabriela", "Paulo", "Roberta"]
nome_aleatorio = random.choice(lista_de_nomes) # Retorna um nome aleatório.
```

Sendo assim, basta você passar todas as suas listas para esta função e depois adicionar à lista retornada os dados inseridos pelo usuário. Veja o código abaixo:

```
import random

A, B, C, D = [], [], [], []

for k in range(12):

    nome = input('Digite seu nome: ')
    numero = int(input('Um numero: '))
    outro = int(input('Outro numero: '))

    lista = random.choice([A, B, C, D])
    lista.append(nome + " " + str(numero) +" " + str(outro))
```

Comment: Amigo, como faço para essas listas serem  limitadas a 3 conjuntos de nome, numero e outro?

Comment: Como essa é uma outra dúvida, crie uma nova questão no site sobre.